# Is a shuffle algebra transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The shuffle algebra on two letters a and b is the polynomial algebra, over the rationals generated by the variables $f_w$ where $w$ is a word in the letters a and b, potentially empty, with the relations coming from the shuffle product.

My question is: is the shuffle algebra a purely transcendental algebra over the rationals?

For example, the degree 1 generators are $f_a, f_b$, and the degree 2 generators are $f_{aa}, f_{ab}, f_{ba}, f_{bb}$. There are already algebraic relations amongst the degree 2 generators. For example, $f_a^2 = 2f_{aa}$, similarly for b, but also $f_af_b=f_{ab}+f_{ba}$. So that the degree lesser equal to 2 part of the algebra is generated by the 3 generators: $f_a,f_b, f_{ab}$ as a module over the rationals. However, it could happen that these 3 terms are not algebraically independent. I.e. that they satisfy a rational polynomial equation in 3 variables.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffle_algebra), the shuffle algebra over the rationals is isomorphic to a polynomial algebra on a certain set of generators. Have you looked in to this?

Comment: I haven't, I guess I would be interested in a proof or a reference to this claim. Thanks a lot anyways for reaffirming my intuition.

Comment: A little more googling turns up [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394621/the-shuffle-algebra-over-the-rationals-is-isomorphic-to-the-polynomial-algebra-i) with some references. I'd encourage you to do a little more searching in the future - it can be surprising how much you can find with some poking around.

Comment: Thank you very much and I whole heartedly agree.